# ¿Se puede crear un operador nuevo en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operador

Necesito usar este operador lógico: ⇒  el cual estará inserto en un string de esta forma:

```
var mystring = "(true ⇒ false) ⇒ true";
```

De esa forma debería poder evaluar esa expresión con `eval(mystring)` y me retorne el valor de verdad.

Pero JavaScript no lo soporta, ¿hay alguna forma de poder crearlo? tiene ciertas reglas bien básicas, incluso se puede simular con esta función que recibe dos variables booleanas:

```
function Condicional(v1,v2){
    return (!v1)||v2;               //formula de una condicional
}
```

pero esa función no podrá aplicarse a cualquier otro tipo de operación en la que use el ⇒, o por lo menos no se me ha ocurrido cómo.

Tal vez haya un lugar en donde yo mismo pueda definir ese operador lógico para que JavaScript me lo reconozca, no lo sé, quizá en el mismo lugar en donde están definidos los demás como el "!", "&&", "||", "==="...

¿Es posible?

**edit**

Necesito saber si existe la forma de crear un operador como este: ⇒ pero también necesitaré crear otros dos operadores más, por lo que lo que busco es cómo crear cualquier otro operador distinto a los que javascript ya posee.

Comment: no creo que sea posible amigo.

Comment: @JuanPinzón No, en esta pregunta quiero saber si existe algún lugar en donde pueda crear un nuevo operador, la pregunta que citas es parecida pero no apunta a lo mismo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé lo que quieres hacer, pero lo que es seguro que *javascript* no es el mejor lenguaje para hacerlo. Lo que pareces buscar es algo que te permita crearte un [DSL (Lenguaje Específico del Dominio)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_espec%C3%ADfico_del_dominio) y, por tus enunciados de Lógica, diría que lo que mejor te encajaría es un lenguaje funcional.

Entre las posibles opciones, hay varios lenguajes funcionales para JVM que permiten una *transpilación* de java a javascript. Con el que tengo más experiencia es con [scala.js](http://scala-js.org/) que te permitiría crear cosas como éstas:

```
package proposionallogic

import scala.scalajs.js.JSApp

object ProposionalLogic {    
    implicit class BooleanRich(a:Boolean) {
        def :=>(b:Boolean):Boolean = !a && b
    }
}

object MyApp extends JSApp {

    import ProposionalLogic._

    def main() = {
        println((true :=> false) :=> true)
    }
}
```

No sé si te puede valer. Te he dejado el proyecto completo en [github](https://github.com/chemacortes/proplogic).

Comment: muchas gracias me ha servido!

Answer (score 3):

No, JavaScript no soporta crear operadores nuevos ni modificar los existentes de manera nativa.  Solo puedes crear funciones.

Comment: no es del todo cierto, en teoría `instanceof` puede alterarse usando un `Symbol` especializado, pero es un caso limite.

Answer (score 0):

No se puede crear un operador, pero si es posible hacer un parser, que te va a permitir evaluar ese tipo de expresiones.

Un ejemplo en javascript que hace algo así es [js-sequence-diagrams](https://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/) que utiliza [jison](http://zaa.ch/jison/) para generar el parser y poder evaluar las expresiones.